# Background color of the Navigation bar not taking the full width

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I had designed a website : `http://newyorkfairandlovely.com/` and it is responsive. But when the site is opened on a computer then the Background color of Navigation Bar is not displaying on the whole screen. The full size of the image is 1950px wide.
When the screen is reduced to 1024px or smaller then it is OK.
This is the css code:

`nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #9362ae;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1950px;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your brackets. The rule you posted is nested under this:

```
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 1224px),
(min-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-width: 1824px)  {
    /* your rule is here */
}
```

So once the screen size increased to greater than 1224px, your rules are no longer applied.

This is an example of why it's a good idea to properly indent your code.

Comment: just looked and saw the issue, came back to post, and you beat me to it :)

Comment: @Travesty3 : What is the solution then? Should I put that code outside it?

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada: Sounds like it. If that nav bar shouldn't be affected by screen size, then it should go outside it.

Comment: @Travesty3: Nope. No changes.

Comment: If you made the changes he suggested and it didn't work, please consider creating a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) with your new CSS and your HTML.  Once you drop your CSS in there, you can click the "Tidy Up" button, and it will properly indent all your CSS so you can see where you may have some mistaken nesting.  If you are unable to find the issue in your jsfiddle, please post a link to it back to us and we can help.

Comment: @guydog28: Here is the link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LV857/2/) . And BTW Thank You for the suggestion on using jsfiddle. This was the first time I have heard about jsfiddle and It seems to be great.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada Thanks.  I'm not sure I see the issue.  I forked your fiddle into [**this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/guydog28/gHh8M/), and added your HTML and clicked run, and the result looked perfect even when i resized the result window very wide.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada As a side note, when I say it works, I mean in firefox and chrome.  Your Responsive MQs don't appear to have any affect in IE.

Comment: @guydog28: Oh! yes. TQ. I hadn't noticed that either. Any Suggestions??? Just for curiosity, Is it necessary to be IE-responsive as Most of the smart phones do not use IE?

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada I mean, its best to support all browsers.  There are windows phones and tablets.  But to make your CSS better, I would suggest just thinking about the different media queries you need to support, put those at the top level, and then their styles inside them, instead of multi-layer nesting your media queries.  It will make it easier to understand what is going on and fix your issues.  Anyway, glad its figured out.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
body { margin : 0; padding : 0; }
```

Body has its own spacing from the HTML.  Different browsers have different settings, but most have some space between the edges of the `<html>` and the `<body>`,
and typically using `body { margin : __; }`

Answer (score 0):

What is the height/width of its parent elements? I believe you could make it cover the whole screen if the parents are all 100%. Also, try setting the `margin-right` to 0. (I also noticed you have a `float:left;` in your css, that might be part of the issue.